# How to draw in more than two canvases HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a proyect and i need to draw in almost 5 canvas. I've created the first canvas successfully but when i put in the code the second i only can draw on this latest canvas.

I read than the problem can be the context("2d") i tryed to separate saving in a different ctx varaible like, ctx2 or things like this.

This is my code:

HTML

`<!--First Canvas-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div id="contenedor-pizarra-cervical" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
            <canvas id="pizarra-cervical"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

   <!--Second Canvas-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">           
        <div id="contenedor-pizarra-postural" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
            <canvas id="pizarra-postural"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>`

JS OF THE FIRST CANVAS WORKING OK:

`//Canvas Cervical

   var canvasCervical = document.getElementById("pizarra-cervical");
   var ctx = canvasCervical.getContext("2d");
   var painting = document.getElementById("contenedor-pizarra-cervical");
   var paintStyle = getComputedStyle(painting);
   canvasCervical.width = parseInt(paintStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
   canvasCervical.height = parseInt(paintStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));

   var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

   canvasCervical.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
   }, false);


   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
   ctx.lineCap = 'round';
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#7baeb0';

   canvasCervical.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    canvasCervical.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
   }, false);

   canvasCervical.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    canvasCervical.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false)
   },false);

   var onPaint = function (){
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
   };`

Comment: Assume you are you requesting the second canvas by its id? `document.getElementById("pizarra-postural");` Maybe post the non working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require the same behaviour to happen on multiple canvasses, then you could define the configuration logic in its own function, providing the `canvas` element as an argument, like this:

```js
let configureCanvas = canvas => {  
  let painting = canvas.parentNode;
  let paintStyle = getComputedStyle(painting);
  let mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };  
  let onPaint = () => {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  };
  
  canvas.width = parseInt(paintStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
  canvas.height = parseInt(paintStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));

  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#7baeb0';
  
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
  }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false)
  }, false);
  
  canvas.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });
}

configureCanvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-cervical"));
configureCanvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-postural"));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<!--First Canvas-->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
  <div id="contenedor-pizarra-cervical" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
    <canvas id="pizarra-cervical"></canvas>
    <button class="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Second Canvas-->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
  <div id="contenedor-pizarra-postural" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
    <canvas id="pizarra-postural"></canvas>
    <button class="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Taking this a step further, I'd suggest defining your own Class to handle the initialisation, configuration and event handlers of your `canvas` elements, but that's well outside the remit of this question.

Comment: Thanks Rory, i try with your code and it's work OK. If you have time I need to ask you one more question... i need to use a button to clear the draw of the specific canvas, i use this code: 
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
but this clear all the canvas. Can you help me?

Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you can call that line of code from an event handler bound to a button related to the `canvas` you want to clear. I updated the answer with an example for you

Comment: Rory, one more question.. I'm trying to save with html2canvas, i have the "program" working correctly but this only works when i have only 1 canvas in the function than you made. When i have 2 or more canvas the program saves a "total black" photo.

Comment: I'd guess you need a loop to iterate through all the canvas elements, not just the first one. I'd suggest starting a new question for it, if you haven't already :)

Comment: Hey Rory! thanks again... i had to do an ask yesterday: This is the link of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379753/convert-canvas-draw-in-a-photo?noredirect=1#comment117355242_66379753