# CONVERT CANVAS DRAW IN A PHOTO

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

i need to capture 4 canvas at the same page with the same button. Thanks to the stack overflow comunity i i could draw and delete in the 4 canvas separately... but now i'm in troubble, i'm ussing html2canvas library and if only exist one canvas, the capture it's correctly but when i add 2 or more canvas the program returns a total black photo, i try to save the canvas.toDataURL(); filtering by canvas with an if previously but the value it's always the same... This is my code:

PD: I HAVE A BUTTON IN A TOP OF THE PAGE BECAUSE I DON'T WANT TO SUBMIT THE FORM ... Exist any way to do the captures and the submit with the same button?

HTML:`

```
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="pt-5">Motivo de la consulta:</h5>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="motivoConsulta" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <div id="contenedor-pizarra-cervical" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
                    <canvas class="pizarra" id="pizarra-cervical"></canvas>
                    <p class="btn btn-danger p-2 w-100 mx-auto limpiar">Limpiar dibujo</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">           
                <div id="contenedor-pizarra-postural" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
                    <canvas class="pizarra" id="pizarra-postural"></canvas>
                    <p class="btn btn-danger p-2 w-100 mx-auto limpiar">Limpiar dibujo</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

                <div id="contenedor-pizarra-sacroiliaco" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
                        <canvas class="pizarra" id="pizarra-sacroiliaco"></canvas>
                        <p class="btn btn-danger p-2 w-100 mx-auto limpiar">Limpiar dibujo</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

                <div id="contenedor-pizarra-musculos" class="contenedor-pizarra mx-auto">
                    <canvas class="pizarra" id="pizarra-musculos"></canvas>
                    <p class="btn btn-danger p-2 w-100 mx-auto limpiar">Limpiar dibujo</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                
            <table class="table table-dark table-bordered w-75 mx-auto mb-5">
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">INDICE DE DOLOR INICIAL</th>
                        <th scope="col">INDICE DE DOLOR FINAL</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="idi" class="form-control w-100 text-center" required>
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">3</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="idf" class="form-control w-100 text-center" required>
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">3</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <p onClick="doCapture()" id="btnCargarSesion" class="btn btn-dark w-50 my-5">CARGAR SESIÓN</p>
                <button type="submit" class="d-none btn btn-dark w-50 my-5">CARGAR SESION</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>`
```

JS:

`var a = "a";
var b = "b";
var c = "c";
var d = "d";

let configureCanvas = canvas => {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let painting = canvas.parentNode;
  let paintStyle = getComputedStyle(painting);
  canvas.width = parseInt(paintStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
  canvas.height = parseInt(paintStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));

  let mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
  }, false);

  if(canvas == document.getElementById("pizarra-musculos")) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 12;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 8, 53, 0.02)';

  }else{
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#e34f54';
  };



  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false)
  }, false);

  var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  canvas.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });


}


// Inizialización de CANVAS

configureCanvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-cervical"));
// configureCanvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-postural"));
// configureCanvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-sacroiliaco"));
// configureCanvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-musculos"));

// Caputrar dibujos


function doCapture() {

  html2canvas(document.getElementById("pizarra-cervical")).then(function (canvas) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "php/save-capture.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send("image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9));

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };
  });

}`

PHP:

`<?php

$image = $_POST["image"];
$image = explode(";", $image)[1];
$image = explode(",", $image)[1];
$image = str_replace(" ", "+", $image);

$randomNumber = rand(); 
$date = date('d-m-y');
$image = base64_decode($image);
file_put_contents("uploads/".$date.$randomNumber.".jpeg", $image);`

Comment: Please cut down the code to the minimum needed for readers to reproduce the problem, hopefully appending the converted canvas to the `body` after taking a "screenshot" of a parent element containing some canvas elements. Unfortunately most of the posted code needs to be waded through and  seems irrelevant to the problem :-(

Comment: Hey! thanks for your response, I thought to cut the code but i don't know how to solve the problem with the full code, this problem it's driving me crazy

Comment: Hi, I think html2canvas has bugs. I am finding it works when you make a canvas from the body ( `html2canvas(document.body).then(...)`), but renders elements in the wrong place and clips part of the snapshot if you you try to convert a container element on the page. In my case using a div container with 4 canvas's inside it, `html2canvas(document.getElementById("container")).then(...)` produced bad output. Can you try rendering the whole body and see what you get?

Comment: Hey traktor, thanks for comment my asnwer.. I use a general div that contains all the canvas and html2canvas returns me the 4 draws but obviously in the same picture.. thanks for you help. I don't know how to get a picture for a canvas specific :(